# Why do python list slices extend beyond the length of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, dynamic-arrays, indices

I was trying to use list slices earlier in python, and came across a strange case where I was expecting a particular list slice to cause an error.

Take for instance a list, *a*, with the following elements.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> a[0:4]
>>> [1,2,3,4]
```

Furthermore, using the correct index removes an element

```
>>> a[0:3]
>>> [1,2,3]
```

Can someone make this make sense please? This is making use of list slices quite confusing.

Comment: This makes some things easy to write like e. g. "a[0:2] + [7] + a[2:]" to create a new list with inserted item 7 at position 2.

Answer (score 3):

The second index is exclusive, meaning the last element the slice will return is the one in front of the specified index. Thus, in your example `[0:4]` returns elements in indices 0 to 3.